# How does using a queue instead of pub-sub help detect missing/stolen data?

Tags: architecture, system, message-queue, publish-subscribe

On page 33 of "fundamentals of software architecture", in the "analyze trade-offs" section, the book compares 2 different approaches to sending information from the bid producer to 3 different consumers

1. bid capture
2. bid tracking
3. bid analytics

Approach 1 (figure 2-8) uses pub-sub. Approach 2 (figure 2-9) uses 3 different queues, one for each of the consumers. It then says

> In analyzing the differences, notice first in Figure 2-8 that with a topic, anyone can access bidding data, which introduces a possible issue with data access and
> data security. In the queue model illustrated in Figure 2-9, the data sent to the queue
> can only be accessed by the specific consumer receiving that message. If a rogue service did listen in on a queue, those bids would not be received by the corresponding
> service, and a notification would immediately be sent about the loss of data (and
> hence a possible security breach). In other words, it is very easy to wiretap into a
> topic, but not a queue.

My question is:
How can you detect that the bids were not received by the corresponding service so you can send a notification about the data loss/security breach?

Perhaps intended services have a secret key that the rogue service doesn't have? So once an item is popped but not acknowledged with the right hash we will know that the item was taken by an unauthorized service?

Comment: Are asking about at least once / at most once delivery guarantees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach is for a producer to include a sequential message identifier. Imagine that each message id is the form: 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. So the receiver uses these ids to detect holes.